# wordpress Nayma theme custom sidebar won't show

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a custom sidebar to be on the single page while the entire site uses the custom sidebar. I am creating it with WP visual tools and assign the custom sidebar to the page i need however it shows as disabled. Plese let me know if i am doing something wrong. I searched forums for a while and saw that some people enable their custom sidebars by modifying code. It looks to me like it can be done with visual editor (like i did below) plus i have no access to the server.

I create a new sidebar for my theme
[image]

I go to widgets and set up a picture to my widget
[image]

then i assign the sidebar to the desired page
[image]

after if i go back to widgets it shows me that custom sidebar has nothing in it and that its disabled bc its not used anywhere on the site
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can contact the person who sold you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that when creating a sidebar, I did not enter anything for the slug (thinking it was not necessary). Creating a value for a slug resolved the problem